# Perl script - search for name inside a text file

Tags: regex, perl

```
$filename = "phone.txt";
print "Enter a name to search for: ";
$name = <STDIN>;
open(my $fh, '<', $filename) or die "Can't open $filename: $!";
while(my $line = <$fh>){
      if($line =~ /$name/){
      print $line;
      }
     else{
     print "$name bot found in phone.txt";
    }
}
close $fh;
```

I'm writing a perl script to search for an name from the input stream into a text file named "phone.txt".
If the name is appears on the file it prints the line.
else it will print "$name not found in phone.txt"

I have this so far, but I can't make it work. I did some test and the file opens correctly. The if statement where it says `if($line =~ /$name/)` is the part that doesn't work. I'm not sure if it because I'm using a variable or what.
I also dont know where or how to put the else statement to print in case the name given is not found in the text file without printing for every single line of the file, I just want it to print once.

Comment: What does the text file look like, please? You'll need to keep state (did any line in the text file match?) then print after you've tested all lines.

Comment: Brockman, Chad 920-213-0043 Chad.Brockman@wisconsin.gov
Burdick, Joel 262-323-6738 Joel.Burdick@wisconsin.gov 
Clark, Ben 608-400-2039 Benjamin.Clark@wisconsin.gov
Dailey, Robbie 608-422-1691 Michael.Dailey@wisconsin.gov 
Daniel, Jacques 920-360-2871 Jacques.Daniel@wisconsin.gov

Comment: So if I input "Chad" it should print back "Brockman, Chad 920-213-0043 Chad.Brockman@wisconsin.gov"

Comment: I tried to replace $name for Chad in the if statement and it worked. I think it has to do with the $name

Comment: Please edit the post--the precise format is important but it's difficult to see as a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `$name` contains a newline at the end and the regex
`/$name/`  will not match lines in the `phone.txt`.
With a little tweaks would you please try:

```
$filename = "phone.txt";
print "Enter a name to search for: ";
chomp($name = <STDIN>);
open(my $fh, '<', $filename) or die "Can't open $filename: $!";
while (<$fh>){
    if (/$name/){
        print;
        $found++;
    }
}
if (! $found) {
    print "$name not found in $filename\n";
}
close $fh;
```

Comment: You are not using `use strict; use warnings;` and not using declared variables, which is bad ideas. Also `filename` is probably missing a `$` in front of it.

Answer (score 2):

If it happens that you use Linux then you could just use `grep some_name filename`.

Script from [tshiono](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8572380/tshiono) should do it, but you can specify *some_name* on command line instead.

If you would like to use exact name then pattern should be `/\b$name\b/`.

It is recommended to utilize `use strict; use warnings;` to avoid many potential pitfalls.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $fname = 'filename.txt';
my $name  = shift;
my $count;

chomp $name;

open my $fh, '<', $fname
    or die "Couldn't open $fname";

while( <$fh> ) {
    chomp;
    if( /\b$name\b/ ) {
        say;
        $count++;
    }
}

close $fh;

if( $found ) {
    say "$name found $count times";
} else {
    say "$name not found in $fname";
}
```